# Jbpm Finding Task using Java

Tags: java, jbpm

I want to find the Task Type and No of Task Inside that Particular Diagram using BPMN .xml file

1. How can I find them through Java PI
2. Is there any prebuild methods to find them

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to simply load the process into an engine and then query the model for the information you need. See https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-services/jbpm-kie-services/src/main/java/org/jbpm/kie/services/impl/bpmn2/BPMN2DataServiceImpl.java#L142

Once you have the ksession, you can get the process and (after casting it to WorkflowProcess) you can navigate each of the nodes to find all the data you need.

We have an implementation that does something like that, collect basic information of human tasks etc. and store it in a ProcessDescriptor:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-services/jbpm-kie-services/src/main/java/org/jbpm/kie/services/impl/xml/ServicesProcessDataEventListener.java